# Django template - For loop through two values each time

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

Im working with views and templates.

I've this list in my view

```
[u'kevinelamo', 50, u'kevin', 4200, u'andres', 200, u'user342', 0, u'cateto', 0]
```

and I send it to the template..

In the template is parsed like this automatically:

```
[{"username": "kevinelamo", "time": 50}, {"username": "kevin", "time": 4200}...]
```

I want to iterate like this:

```
{% for username,time in llistat_usuaris %}
<h1>My name is <h1>{{username}}
{{time}}
{% endfor %}
```

But this gave me one char of the list

```
My name is
[
My name is
{
My name is
"
My name is
u
My name is
s
My name is
e
My name is
r
My name is
n
My name is
a
My name is
m
My name is
e
My name is
```

How can I handle it? Thanks

Comment: You need to show how your view is sending the data to the template, and what you mean by "parsed automatically" in the template. From your output it just seems like you're sending it as a string.

Comment: I mean with Parsed automatically that the format is changed when I pass it to the template as you can see in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this list:

```
l = [u'kevinelamo', 50, u'kevin', 4200, u'andres', 200, u'user342', 0, u'cateto', 0]
```

You could convert it to a dictionary:

```
l_dict = dict(zip(l[::2], l[1::2]))
```

Which will make `l_dict`:

```
{u'andres': 200, u'cateto': 0, u'user342': 0, u'kevin': 4200, u'kevinelamo': 50}
```

Then iterate over key value pairs in your template:

```
{% for username, time in l_dict.items %}
    <h1>My name is <h1>{{ username }}
    {{ time }}
{% endfor %}
```